# Move TextBlock around, and Make its size fit to content

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Currently, I have the following XAML code which is able to achieve the following effect.

[image]

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="FacionMetro.Gui.HealthIndicatorView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FacionMetro.Gui"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Name="message" FontSize="22" Text="120 is good" Margin="250,0,-250,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Name="arrow" FontSize="22" Text="▼" Margin="350,0,-350,0" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.Background >
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#ff00ff00"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#ffffff00" Offset="0.25" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#ffffa500" Offset="0.75" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#ffff0000" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center">40</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center">60</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center">100</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center">120</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**I wish to move the x-position of the triangle arrow and message (?? is good) around dynamically, according to color bar current value.**

[image]

My current code snippet is as below. It is not workable yet.

```
public sealed partial class HealthIndicatorView : UserControl
{
    public HealthIndicatorView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        // Margin X. For both left and right sides.
        double offsetX = this.ActualWidth / 10;

        if (value < 40) {
            // I wish to move the message and arrow the left most. How?
            // The below code is having error :
            // Cannot modify the return value of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable
            message.Margin.Left = offsetX;
            arrow.Margin.Left = offsetX;
            return;
        }

        if (value > 120) {
            // messageSize and arrowSize are incorrect. As the TextBlock isn't fit to the string content.
            double messageSize = message.Width;
            double arrowSize = arrow.Width;

            double rightMostPosForMessage = this.ActualWidth - offsetX - messageSize;
            double rightMostPosForArrow = this.ActualWidth - offsetX - arrowSize;

            // I wish to move the message and arrow the right most. How?
            // The below code is having error :
            // Cannot modify the return value of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable
            message.Margin.Left = offsetX;
            arrow.Margin.Left = offsetX;
        }

    }
}
```

1. **How I can move the `TextBlock` around according to color bar value?** (To know what does *move around* means, see the 2 different screenshot, when the color bar value is 40 and 120 respectively)
2. **How I can make `TextBlock`, to exactly fit to the string content? I need this, as I need to know the space occupied by string content, so that I will not move them out of bound.** (As you can see in "120 is good" screenshot, TextBlock is occupying too much space although the string content is just a short message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Move TextBlock around

To move the `TextBlock` around, you need to define

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="message" FontSize="22" Text="120 is good">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="messageTransform" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    ...
```

Then in your C# code.

`messageTransform.X = offsetX;`

### Fit to The String Content

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="arrow" FontSize="22" Text="▼" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="arrowTransform" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>                
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Use `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`

Answer (score 0):

to answer your Second Question.

You can add the `TextBlock` to a `Grid` and set the `Width` to **Auto**. Also for `TextBlock.Width` bind it to the `Grid.Width`. That way the width will be automatically adjusted to content.

```
message.Width="{Binding ElementName=NameOfYourGrid}"
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?         <Grid Name="messageGrid" Width="Auto">
            <TextBlock Name="message" FontSize="22" Text="120 is good" Width="{Binding ElementName=messageGrid}"/>
        </Grid>

Comment: No error. It doesn't make TextBlock size shrink to fit to the content of message string.

Comment: you think it's because of crazy Margin's? `Margin="250,0,-250,0"`

Comment: No sure. But I figure out the answer for 2nd question. Still looking around for 1st question.

Comment: you should put your `TextBlock` into a `Canvas` than you can define `X,Y` position for it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18851/discussion-between-yan-cheng-cheok-and-mayank)